# JqGrid not loading data from Controller/Model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have an MVC project and I am trying to get a JqGrid to display data from my model, being supplied by my controller.  The grid shows up, but no data is loaded...(I have confirmed that the List being passed via the controller has data in it.)

Here is my Controller:

```
 public ActionResult getGroupData()
    {
        var Nacho = db.CMC_GRGR_GROUP.ToList<CMC_GRGR_GROUP>();
        return this.Json(Nacho);

    }
```

Here is my View:

```
<table id="list" ></table>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var myGrid = $("#list");
        myGrid.jqGrid({
            caption     : "Groups",
            url         : '/Groups/getGroupData/',
            datatype   : "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
            mtype   : 'GET',
            colNames: ['GRGR_CK', 'GRGR_ID', 'GRGR_NAME'],
            colModel: [
                            { name: 'GRGR_CK'                },
                            { name: 'GRGR_ID'            },
                            { name: 'GRGR_NAME'          },
            ],
            rowNum: 5
        });
    });
</script>
```

Why is no data being loaded?!?

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
public ActionResult getGroupData()
    {
        var Nacho = db.CMC_GRGR_GROUP.ToList<CMC_GRGR_GROUP>();
        return Json(Nacho,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);

    }
```